# Replace exploration by skill, and then exploring in Pathfinder

Tags: pathfinder-adventure

If I use Kyra's skill (instead of the first free explore, I shuffle cards from the discard pile into someone's deck)

[image]

can I explore afterwards by discarding BotG?

[image]

According to the rule book, the free given exploration

> must be your first exploration for the turn.

If I don't do it, then I can't explore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the power is worded "instead of your first exploration". This is referring to the first FREE exploration you get on every turn. So you may either explore or use the cure power. Once that is done, then discarding BofG grants you an additional exploration. If you have a multiple blessings in your hand, you may explore many times in a turn.